# How to close sidenav when I click anywhere of the page in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
**Nav-header.js**
```

The sidebar should not collapse when I am clicking outside of the page in react js. Please help with that.  this is the code I wrote for the side menu. I am a beginner at the react js. Please help

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa'
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData'
import './Navbar.css'
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons'

const Header = () => {
  const [sidebar, setsidebar] = useState(false)
  const showSideBar = () => setsidebar(!sidebar)
  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#1D1D1D' }}>
        <div className='navbar'>
    <Link to="#" className='menu-bars'>
    <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSideBar} color="#009540"/>
          </Link>
          <span className="meny">Meny</span>
        </div>
    <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu' } >
    <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSideBar}>
    <li className='navbar-toggle'>
    <Link to="#" className='menu-bars-logo'>
    <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose/>
    </Link>
          </li>
          {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                <Link to={item.path}>
                  <span>{item.title}</span>
                </Link>
              </li>
            )
          })}
    </ul>
        </nav>
        </IconContext.Provider>
      </>
  )
}
export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp), in react it would look like

```js
return (
  <div onBlur={() => {
    ... do something like setState
  }}>
)
```